# WrapPanel with LastChildFill

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I have a set of usercontrols on a data entry form. To allow maximum use of space these usercontrols are placed in a wrappanel that expands vertically. My form works well but it does not look polished visually. I am typing on a mobile device so cannot post a picture but let me describe it.

Say the form has 3 usercontrols demographics (width 800), Phone #s (width 300), Addresses(width 600). The form itself is 1000 pixels wide.

Now when these user controls are laid out(in the order listed above), demographics will be on the top row and the other two usercontrols will be in the row below.

But the demographics control will only ocupy 800 pixels of the available 1000 pixels in the row. And similarly the bottom row will occupy 900 pixels only. That makes the form look ugly.

What I need is to have the last child in each row stretch its bounding bix (ie its border) to occupy remaining space. So in this case demographics' border will stretch to 1000 pixels and addresses' border will stretch to 700 pixels.

the usercontrol collection is dynamic. The user can create new forms on the fly and change elements and their order.

If the screen size changes the stretched elements are restored to their original widths, the wrap panel rearranges the elements and last child in each row fills the remaining space again.

Hope I was able to explain the situation correctly. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You mean there may as well be only one row with the last element filling it, or three rows where each element fills the entire row?

Comment: And is it Silverlight or WPF? It can't be both.

Comment: In the scenario described above, there are two rows. Row 1 holds demographics and row2 holds phone and addresses provided the wrappanel is 1000 pixels wide but say the panel was shrunk to 800 pixels then there will be 3 rows. One fir each usercontrol. In that case the demographics usercontrol is already as wide as the wrappanel but the other two usercontrols will need to be stretched to 800 width. This is for silverlight. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up writing my own custom panel. In the MeasureOverride, jyst before a new line was created, went back to the last processed control and set its length to control.length + (maximumSize- lineSize).

That seems to work well

Comment: I guess your custom Panel inherits from WrapPanel? Seems like a cool functionality that MS could easily implement, with its appropiate DependencyProperty...

Answer (score 0):

I've done a control for that. I published it at: [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/990854/WPF-WrapPanel-with-fill).

Usage:

```
<wrapPanelWithFill:WrapPanelFill Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBlock Text="Path: " TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
        <TextBox MinWidth="120"  wrapPanelWithFill:WrapPanelFill.UseToFill="True">*</TextBox>
        <Button>Browse...</Button>
</wrapPanelWithFill:WrapPanelFill>
```

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WrapPanelWithFill
{
    public class WrapPanelFill : WrapPanel
    {
        // ******************************************************************
        public static readonly DependencyProperty UseToFillProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("UseToFill", typeof(Boolean), 
            typeof(WrapPanelFill), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

        // ******************************************************************
        public static void SetUseToFill(UIElement element, Boolean value)
        {
            element.SetValue(UseToFillProperty, value);
        }
        // ******************************************************************
        public static Boolean GetUseToFill(UIElement element)
        {
            return (Boolean)element.GetValue(UseToFillProperty);
        }

        // ******************************************************************
        const double DBL_EPSILON = 2.2204460492503131e-016; /* smallest such that 1.0+DBL_EPSILON != 1.0 */

        // ******************************************************************
        private static bool DoubleAreClose(double value1, double value2)
        {
            //in case they are Infinities (then epsilon check does not work)
            if (value1 == value2) return true;
            // This computes (|value1-value2| / (|value1| + |value2| + 10.0)) < DBL_EPSILON
            double eps = (Math.Abs(value1) + Math.Abs(value2) + 10.0) * DBL_EPSILON;
            double delta = value1 - value2;
            return (-eps < delta) && (eps > delta);
        }

        // ******************************************************************
        private static bool DoubleGreaterThan(double value1, double value2)
        {
            return (value1 > value2) && !DoubleAreClose(value1, value2);
        }

        // ******************************************************************
        private bool _atLeastOneElementCanHasItsWidthExpanded = false;

        // ******************************************************************
        /// <summary> 
        /// <see cref="FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride"/>
        /// </summary> 
        protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
        {
            UVSize curLineSize = new UVSize(Orientation);
            UVSize panelSize = new UVSize(Orientation);
            UVSize uvConstraint = new UVSize(Orientation, constraint.Width, constraint.Height);
            double itemWidth = ItemWidth;
            double itemHeight = ItemHeight;
            bool itemWidthSet = !Double.IsNaN(itemWidth);
            bool itemHeightSet = !Double.IsNaN(itemHeight);

            Size childConstraint = new Size(
                (itemWidthSet ? itemWidth : constraint.Width),
                (itemHeightSet ? itemHeight : constraint.Height));

            UIElementCollection children = InternalChildren;

            // EO
            LineInfo currentLineInfo = new LineInfo(); // EO, the way it works it is always like we are on the current line
            _lineInfos.Clear();
            _atLeastOneElementCanHasItsWidthExpanded = false;

            for (int i = 0, count = children.Count; i < count; i++)
            {
                UIElement child = children[i] as UIElement;
                if (child == null) continue;

                //Flow passes its own constrint to children 
                child.Measure(childConstraint);

                //this is the size of the child in UV space 
                UVSize sz = new UVSize(
                    Orientation,
                    (itemWidthSet ? itemWidth : child.DesiredSize.Width),
                    (itemHeightSet ? itemHeight : child.DesiredSize.Height));

                if (DoubleGreaterThan(curLineSize.U + sz.U, uvConstraint.U)) //need to switch to another line 
                {
                    // EO
                    currentLineInfo.Size = curLineSize;
                    _lineInfos.Add(currentLineInfo);

                    panelSize.U = Math.Max(curLineSize.U, panelSize.U);
                    panelSize.V += curLineSize.V;
                    curLineSize = sz;

                    // EO
                    currentLineInfo = new LineInfo();
                    var feChild = child as FrameworkElement;
                    if (GetUseToFill(feChild))
                    {
                        currentLineInfo.ElementsWithNoWidthSet.Add(feChild);
                        _atLeastOneElementCanHasItsWidthExpanded = true;
                    }

                    if (DoubleGreaterThan(sz.U, uvConstraint.U)) //the element is wider then the constrint - give it a separate line
                    {
                        currentLineInfo = new LineInfo();

                        panelSize.U = Math.Max(sz.U, panelSize.U);
                        panelSize.V += sz.V;
                        curLineSize = new UVSize(Orientation);
                    }
                }
                else //continue to accumulate a line
                {
                    curLineSize.U += sz.U;
                    curLineSize.V = Math.Max(sz.V, curLineSize.V);

                    // EO
                    var feChild = child as FrameworkElement;
                    if (GetUseToFill(feChild))
                    {
                        currentLineInfo.ElementsWithNoWidthSet.Add(feChild);
                        _atLeastOneElementCanHasItsWidthExpanded = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (curLineSize.U > 0)
            {
                currentLineInfo.Size = curLineSize;
                _lineInfos.Add(currentLineInfo);
            }

            //the last line size, if any should be added 
            panelSize.U = Math.Max(curLineSize.U, panelSize.U);
            panelSize.V += curLineSize.V;

            // EO
            if (_atLeastOneElementCanHasItsWidthExpanded)
            {
                return new Size(constraint.Width, panelSize.Height);
            }

            //go from UV space to W/H space
            return new Size(panelSize.Width, panelSize.Height);
        }

        // ************************************************************************
        private struct UVSize
        {
            internal UVSize(Orientation orientation, double width, double height)
            {
                U = V = 0d;
                _orientation = orientation;
                Width = width;
                Height = height;
            }

            internal UVSize(Orientation orientation)
            {
                U = V = 0d;
                _orientation = orientation;
            }

            internal double U;
            internal double V;
            private Orientation _orientation;

            internal double Width
            {
                get { return (_orientation == Orientation.Horizontal ? U : V); }
                set { if (_orientation == Orientation.Horizontal) U = value; else V = value; }
            }
            internal double Height
            {
                get { return (_orientation == Orientation.Horizontal ? V : U); }
                set { if (_orientation == Orientation.Horizontal) V = value; else U = value; }
            }
        }

        // ************************************************************************
        private class LineInfo
        {
            public List<UIElement> ElementsWithNoWidthSet = new List<UIElement>();
            //          public double SpaceLeft = 0;
            //          public double WidthCorrectionPerElement = 0;
            public UVSize Size;
            public double Correction = 0;
        }

        private List<LineInfo> _lineInfos = new List<LineInfo>();

        // ************************************************************************
        /// <summary>
        /// <see cref="FrameworkElement.ArrangeOverride"/> 
        /// </summary> 
        protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
        {
            int lineIndex = 0;
            int firstInLine = 0;
            double itemWidth = ItemWidth;
            double itemHeight = ItemHeight;
            double accumulatedV = 0;
            double itemU = (Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal ? itemWidth : itemHeight);
            UVSize curLineSize = new UVSize(Orientation);
            UVSize uvFinalSize = new UVSize(Orientation, finalSize.Width, finalSize.Height);
            bool itemWidthSet = !Double.IsNaN(itemWidth);
            bool itemHeightSet = !Double.IsNaN(itemHeight);
            bool useItemU = (Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal ? itemWidthSet : itemHeightSet);

            UIElementCollection children = InternalChildren;

            for (int i = 0, count = children.Count; i < count; i++)
            {
                UIElement child = children[i] as UIElement;
                if (child == null) continue;

                UVSize sz = new UVSize(
                    Orientation,
                    (itemWidthSet ? itemWidth : child.DesiredSize.Width),
                    (itemHeightSet ? itemHeight : child.DesiredSize.Height));

                if (DoubleGreaterThan(curLineSize.U + sz.U, uvFinalSize.U)) //need to switch to another line 
                {
                    arrangeLine(lineIndex, accumulatedV, curLineSize.V, firstInLine, i, useItemU, itemU, uvFinalSize);
                    lineIndex++;

                    accumulatedV += curLineSize.V;
                    curLineSize = sz;

                    if (DoubleGreaterThan(sz.U, uvFinalSize.U)) //the element is wider then the constraint - give it a separate line 
                    {
                        //switch to next line which only contain one element 
                        arrangeLine(lineIndex, accumulatedV, sz.V, i, ++i, useItemU, itemU, uvFinalSize);

                        accumulatedV += sz.V;
                        curLineSize = new UVSize(Orientation);
                    }
                    firstInLine = i;
                }
                else //continue to accumulate a line
                {
                    curLineSize.U += sz.U;
                    curLineSize.V = Math.Max(sz.V, curLineSize.V);
                }
            }

            //arrange the last line, if any
            if (firstInLine < children.Count)
            {
                arrangeLine(lineIndex, accumulatedV, curLineSize.V, firstInLine, children.Count, useItemU, itemU, uvFinalSize);
            }

            return finalSize;
        }

        // ************************************************************************
        private void arrangeLine(int lineIndex, double v, double lineV, int start, int end, bool useItemU, double itemU, UVSize uvFinalSize)
        {
            double u = 0;
            bool isHorizontal = (Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal);

            Debug.Assert(lineIndex < _lineInfos.Count);

            LineInfo lineInfo = _lineInfos[lineIndex];
            double lineSpaceAvailableForCorrection = Math.Max(uvFinalSize.U - lineInfo.Size.U, 0);
            double perControlCorrection = 0;
            if (lineSpaceAvailableForCorrection > 0 && lineInfo.Size.U > 0)
            {
                perControlCorrection = lineSpaceAvailableForCorrection / lineInfo.ElementsWithNoWidthSet.Count;
                if (double.IsInfinity(perControlCorrection))
                {
                    perControlCorrection = 0;
                }
            }
            int indexOfControlToAdjustSizeToFill = 0;
            UIElement uIElementToAdjustNext = indexOfControlToAdjustSizeToFill < lineInfo.ElementsWithNoWidthSet.Count ? lineInfo.ElementsWithNoWidthSet[indexOfControlToAdjustSizeToFill] : null;

            UIElementCollection children = InternalChildren;
            for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
            {
                UIElement child = children[i] as UIElement;
                if (child != null)
                {
                    UVSize childSize = new UVSize(Orientation, child.DesiredSize.Width, child.DesiredSize.Height);
                    double layoutSlotU = (useItemU ? itemU : childSize.U);

                    if (perControlCorrection > 0 && child == uIElementToAdjustNext)
                    {
                        layoutSlotU += perControlCorrection;

                        indexOfControlToAdjustSizeToFill++;
                        uIElementToAdjustNext = indexOfControlToAdjustSizeToFill < lineInfo.ElementsWithNoWidthSet.Count ? lineInfo.ElementsWithNoWidthSet[indexOfControlToAdjustSizeToFill] : null;
                    }

                    child.Arrange(new Rect(
                        (isHorizontal ? u : v),
                        (isHorizontal ? v : u),
                        (isHorizontal ? layoutSlotU : lineV),
                        (isHorizontal ? lineV : layoutSlotU)));
                    u += layoutSlotU;
                }
            }
        }

        // ************************************************************************

    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. The code looks much cleaner than mine:) I am in the process of porting the code over to a Windows app (from Silverlight). I will give this a go when I get to the UI part. Thanks